# Hiding a div when the innerHTML is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I am pretty new to jQuery but I am trying to get a code setup which hides a div when the 'innerHTML' is null. I tried using the code below. But it doesn't work! Where is my fault??

```
if (($("#php-errors").html).length) {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line, and using `.show()` and `.hide()` methods:

```
var hasCont = $("#php-errors").contents().length ? $("#php-errors").show() : $("#php-errors").hide();
```

Using the *ternary operator* that says:

- (define var) **statement**         **?**
- action **if statement is true**    **:**
- action **if statement is false**   **;**

#### *[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NwT6E/1/)*

---

A good practice would be to cache your element inside a var, let's call it `var $el`, and use it like:

```
var $el = $("#php-errors");
var hasCont = $el.contents().length ? $el.show() : $el.hide();
```

Much more readable, and
it will save you some micro processing time ;) but it really helps in terms of cross-function reusability (if defined outside the function.)

Comment: Why don't use: $el.is(":empty") ?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("#php-errors").html().length) {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "none");
}
```

**Correction:**

`($("#php-errors").html).length` should be `$("#php-errors").html().length`

Answer (score 2):

You can clean your code a little like this.

It also uses the `innerHTML` property as the condition part of the ternary expression. If there's any content, it'll return and set "block", if not, then "none".

```
$("#php-errors").css("display", function() {
    return this.innerHTML ? "block" : "none";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WKWNc/2/

---

***update:***

If this only runs when the page loads, you could initially have it set to "block", and then do this.

```
$("#php-errors:empty").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WKWNc/1/

Or the opposite, have it set to "none", and show it if not empty.

```
$("#php-errors:not(:empty)").show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WKWNc/

Answer (score 2):

Just to add the css way that will not require javascript in case someone else needs it:

```
.php-errors:empty { display: none; }
```

Will Match:

```
<div class="php-errors"></div>
<div class="php-errors"><!-- test --></div>
```

Will **Not** Match:

```
<div class="php-errors"> </div>
<div class="php-errors">
   <!-- test -->
</div>

<div class="php-errors">
</div>
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it seems you just want:

```
$("#php-errors").toggle();
```

I can see no case where you want to set the display to either `block` or `none` if none is already set.

Are you sure your logic isn't redundant?

Answer (score 0):

I think u missed compare , try this

```
if ($("#php-errors").html() == "") {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $("#php-errors").css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: It's sufficient to check for its "falsy-ness"

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var $php_errors = $("#php-errors");

if ($php_errors.is(":empty")) {
    $php_errors.hide()
}
else {
    $php_errors.show();
}
```

hope it helps